# The "continue" keyword in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to count how many times the "continue" keyword (I don't know the proper term for it) is used in a for loop? I have a program that prints out "[>] Adding follower #" + str(index + 1)" after every successful loop. However, the follower number is inaccurate because sometimes the condition is met where the continue keyword is executed instead of the normal part of the loop. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: No, it is not possible to count the number of times *continue* is called. Just increase your successful-loop-counter before doing a *continue*.

Comment: So, this is XY problem - you don't want to count the cases in which `continue` is execute (in order to subtract them) but you need to count the successful iterations right. Post [mre] of your code, so that we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your code is a little difficult; however this should be appliable to any for loop.

```py
continue_count = 0

for x in my_iterable:
   if some_condition:
      continue_count += 1
      continue
```

Comment: This is clearly XY problem - OP wants to count how many times the continue statement is executed in order to subtract the number from the other count they perform.